# How change name of contextMenuStrip item

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I have contextMenuStrip and there be always 3 items. First item will be start/stop for enabling and disabling timer. When timer is enabled I need to change text to "stop",when timer disabled-"start". Whats the most simply solution for dynamic text change for first item?

Comment: Set its Text property, `contextMenuStrip1.Items[0].Text = "Stop";`

Comment: Although the task is rather trivial, it's not really a good UE to have menu elements change its name and functionality. It's more appropriate to have 2 menu items; Start and Stop and disable the one that's not valid. Much like Microsoft does it in the service control applet. Just my 2c of course.

Comment: Hmm,interesting approach,maybe i try to do it. And thanks for comments:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contextMenuStrip.Items[0].Text = "your-text-here";
```